# Buscar valores em JSON por múltiplas chaves

Tags: javascript, json

Eu tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
{
  "$SP": {
    "0": "92",
    "1": "00:01:36.340",
    "2": "00:05:48.929\n"
  },
  "$MT": {
    "0": "91",
    "1": "00:00:34.187",
    "2": "00:18:44.001\n"
  }
}
```

Preciso de uma função que procure pelo nome da chave e em seguida procure um número dentro dela, e retorne o objeto inteiro.
Por exemplo:

```
json("$MT", "91");
```

retorno esperado:

```
"$MT": {
            "0": "91",
            "1": "00:00:34.187",
            "2": "00:18:44.001\n"
        }
```

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
var json = {}; 
function addJson(data){
   var chave; 
   for(var i in data){
      if(i == 0){ 
         chave = data[i]; 
         json[chave] = {}; 
      }else{
         json[chave][i-1] = data[i]; 
      }
   }
}
```

Porém me retorna apenas uma única chave.

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o seu problema elaborar um exemplo melhor?

Comment: eu recebo este json a cada segundo, preciso filtrar pela primeira chave que seria no exemplo "$MT" e depois um segundo filtro pelo valor "91" e a expectativa é retonar o objeto inteiro para que eu consiga utilizar os demais valores dele

Comment: Era bom você dar mais exemplos pq tá dificil de entender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente acessar o atributo pela primeira chave e depois utilizar a função [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) para verificar se o valor está contido dentro do objeto

```js
const buscar = (dados, chave, conteudo) => {
  const item = dados[chave];
  
  return Object.values(item).indexOf(conteudo) !== -1 ? item : null;
};

// Teste
const json = {
  "$SP": {
    "0": "92",
    "1": "00:01:36.340",
    "2": "00:05:48.929\n"
  },
  "$MT": {
    "0": "91",
    "1": "00:00:34.187",
    "2": "00:18:44.001\n"
  }
};

console.log(buscar(json, '$SP', '92'));
console.log(buscar(json, '$MT', '91'));
```

> [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
>
> O método Object.values() retorna um array com os valores das propriedades de um dado objeto...

Comment: eita, estou fazendo algo errado pois ainda não consegui ter o retorno em varias chamadas

eu recebo o json a cada segundo ou seja, eu recebo  
"$MT": {
    "0": "91",
    "1": "00:00:34.187",
    "2": "00:18:44.001\n"
  }

no próximo segundo 
"$SP": {
    "0": "92",
    "1": "00:01:36.340",
    "2": "00:05:48.929\n"
  }

quando vou acessar o buscar pela segunda vez ele não me retorna

Answer (score 3):

Eu fiz da seguinte forma, de acordo com o que eu entendi da pergunta, se ficou algo obscuro comente aqui embaixo que eu te ajudo.

```js
let meuJSON = {
  "$SP": {
    "0": "92",
    "1": "00:01:36.340",
    "2": "00:05:48.929\n"
  },
  "$MT": {
    "0": "91",
    "1": "00:00:34.187",
    "2": "00:18:44.001\n"
  }
}

const getJSON = (estado, conteudo, json) => {
  const jsonEmArray = Object.values(json[estado]) // Transforma os valores em Array
  let resultado = {}

  jsonEmArray.forEach(elemento => {
    if (elemento === conteudo) resultado = json[estado]
  })

  return resultado
}

let jsonFiltrado = getJSON('$SP', '92', meuJSON)

console.log(jsonFiltrado)
```

Answer (score 0):

@EduardoRibeiro funciona quando chamo apenas uma vez a getJSON, quando chamo por exemplo

```
let jsonFiltrado = getJSON('$SP', '92', meuJSON)
let jsonFiltrado2 = getJSON('$MT', '91', meuJSON)

console.log(jsonFiltrado)
console.log(jsonFiltrado2)
```

não retorna nenhuma das duas chamadas

```js
let meuJSON = {
  "$SP": {
    "0": "92",
    "1": "00:01:36.340",
    "2": "00:05:48.929\n"
  },
  "$MT": {
    "0": "91",
    "1": "00:00:34.187",
    "2": "00:18:44.001\n"
  }
}

const getJSON = (estado, conteudo, json) => {
  const jsonEmArray = Object.values(json[estado]) // Transforma os valores em Array
  let resultado = {}

  jsonEmArray.forEach(elemento => {
    if (elemento === conteudo) resultado = json[estado]
  })

  return resultado
}

let jsonFiltrado = getJSON('$SP', '92', meuJSON)

console.log(jsonFiltrado)
```